# Output a Vue.js component - unknown custom element

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to output a Vue.js component on my page, I was following the documentation but I'm getting the following error -

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <contacts> - did you register the component correctly?
```

This is my code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('contacts', require('./components/Contacts.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

The component code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Contacts list</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

My blade file:

```
<div class="container">
    <contacts></contacts>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I was running `npm run watch` so that's why the VueJS Component wasn't loading.